# Sphero License page down

Tags: sphero-api

I am trying to "Start a New Project" in my Sphero Developer console so that I can add my new Sphero app "Sphero Watch Control":
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamicu.spheroWatchControl

Everything seems fine except for the license page not being found.

https://developer.gosphero.com/pages/license

I would really like to read the license before agreeing to it so could someone let me know how I can get to it?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is a question for the web site's support department, not SO.

Comment: I agree that this does not sound like a SO question, but I did a live chat with the site and they said ask the question here. I am not sure what else I am left with but to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Upgrade, if you have not seen already, the issue has been resolved. The correct link is now: http://www.gosphero.com/privacy/

Thanks for asking, and sorry it took us so long to get back to you.